# a button post the value to select in a dropdown list of a form in another page

Tags: javascript, html, post, select, submit

sorry for my english.
I wonder if it's possible to post with a submit button of the page A, a specific value to pre-select an item in a dropdown list of a form witch is in the page B.

I have that in the page A :

```
<form action="/form-test-pour-repo/" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="acces" value="choix 3">Choisir le 3</button>
</form>
```

and a form with a select in the page B

```
<select data-required_mark="required" data-field_type="select" data-original_id="liste">
    <option value="">liste</option>
        <option value="choix 1">je veux le 1</option>
        <option value="choix 2">je veux le 2</option>
        <option value="choix 3">je veux le 3</option>
</select>
```

But I didn't succeed to pre-select "choix 3" when I arrive on the page B

Any help will be much appreciated

Caroline

Comment: It's possible. What language are you using on the sever?

Comment: i use php. I thought my need would use JavaScript

Comment: Is page A's form only to pre-select options? Are the options user-specific or contain personal/private information? Is page B public (as in: reachable by direct URL, independent of page A)? Maybe `method=get` is better than `post`, because then the URL can be shared and behaves the same since the payload (the pre-select choice) is part of the URL.

Comment: Page A, the button is only use to send the pre-select 'choix 3'. Page B, the select into the form doesn't depend of any user and doesn't contain any personal/private information at all. 
Page B, it is a simple form with 3 discussion topics in a drop-down list, but when you come from page A, the button on page A is made to pre-select the third of the discussion topics in the form on page B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recommend you use a `get` method since the URL can be bookmarked or shared.

Page A

```
<form action="url_of_page_b.php" method="get">
    <button type="submit" name="acces" value="choix 3">Choisir le 3</button>
</form>
```

Page B

```
<?php $choix = $_GET["acces"] ?? ''; ?>
<select data-required_mark="required" data-field_type="select" data-original_id="liste">
    <option value="">liste</option>
    <option value="choix 1" <?= $choix == 'choix 1' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>je veux le 1</option>
    <option value="choix 2" <?= $choix == 'choix 2' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>je veux le 2</option>
    <option value="choix 3" <?= $choix == 'choix 3' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>je veux le 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I did what you propose, but it didn't work. I get 'choix+3' in the page B URL, so I delete all the space in my code, but that doesn't work better.

Comment: @carosch you don't have to alter the URL. I've updated my answer. Kindly check it out

Comment: Other than using GET, I fail to see any difference to my answer. If the value is null, it would not select anything anyway

Comment: @mplungjan you're right. Since the OP is just trying to pass a non sensitive data from one page to the other, I think the `get` method is better suited for the job. Also, you didn't check if `$_POST["access"]` isset before assigning it to a variable. This might throw a warning. I'm not saying my answer is better, I just provided an alternative.

Comment: @carosch `choix+3` is the same as `choix 3`. The browser replace all spaces with a `+` sign in the address bar.

Comment: ok, I keped the space, tried again, it doesn't work.
The result is: <select data-required_mark="required" data-field_type="select" data-original_id="liste">
 <option value="">liste</option>
 <option value="choix 1" <?php="" $choix="=" 'choix="" 1'="" ?="" 'selected'="" :="" ''=""> &gt;je veux le 1</option>
 <option value="choix 2" <?php="" $choix="=" 'choix="" 2'="" ?="" 'selected'="" :="" ''=""> &gt;je veux le 2</option>
 <option value="choix 3" <?php="" $choix="=" 'choix="" 3'="" ?="" 'selected'="" :="" ''=""> &gt;je veux le 3</option>
</select>.  Why I have > before each value?

Comment: @carosch any of the answers should work for you. I think there is an issue somewhere in your code. Try and add some more details to the question. Maybe some screenshots will help.

Comment: Hello, I tried to test this with an html editor, and it works. So something goes wrong in wordpress with CF7 plugin but I don't understand what. Thank you

Comment: I finally find out why. It's because it's impossible to add our own php code into a wordpress webpage, so my mistake, I didn't remember that fact

Answer (score 1):

You can use JS if you want. For example via sessionStorage or by setting a value on the server:

```
$choix = array_key_exists('acces', $_POST) ? $_POST["acces"] : "";
?>
<script>
document.querySelector("[data-original_id=liste]").value="<?= $choix] ?>";
</script>
```

Without JS:

```
$choix = array_key_exists('acces', $_POST) ? $_POST["acces"] : "";
?>
<select data-required_mark="required" data-field_type="select" data-original_id="liste">
  <option value="">liste</option>
  <option value="choix 1"<?= $choix === "choix 1" ? " selected" : "" ?>>je veux le 1</option>
  <option value="choix 2"<?= $choix === "choix 2" ? " selected" : "" ?>>je veux le 2</option>
  <option value="choix 3"<?= $choix === "choix 3" ? " selected" : "" ?>>je veux le 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I did what you propose into the second bloc (without JS), but it didn't work. I get 'choix+3' in the page B URL, so I delete all the space in my code, but that doesn't work better.

Comment: You should not get choix+3 if you use post. Anyway, what does the code look like when you right-click on the select and choose "inspect"

Comment: I tried with POST. I get this :
<!--?php $choix = $_POST["access"]; ?-->
<select data-required_mark="required" data-field_type="select" data-original_id="liste">
 <option value="">liste</option>
 <option value="choix 1" <?="$choix" =="choix 1" ?="" 'selected'="" :="" ''="">&gt;je veux le 1</option>
 <option value="choix 2" <?="$choix" =="choix 2" ?="" 'selected'="" :="" ''="">&gt;je veux le 2</option>
 <option value="choix 3" <?="$choix" =="choix 3" ?="" 'selected'="" :="" ''="">&gt;je veux le 3</option>
</select>

Comment: Why is the php to get the choix commented out? `<!--?php $choix = $_POST["access"]; ?-->`

Comment: You can use `$choix = array_key_exists('access', $_POST) ? $_POST["access"] : "";` in both cases, I just forgot to change it in the second

Comment: I suppose it is commented because I copied it from the DevTools elements

Comment: It seems you are not able to add our suggestions or test the results. It is very hard to help when the answer is "it does not work"

Comment: Also I spelled access with two sses - changed now

Answer (score 0):

## Session storage

We can use the [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)'s [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to save the choice across pages.

**Page A** can save the choice into `sessionStorage`:

```js
document.forms[0].addEventListener("submit", evt => {
  const button = evt.submitter;
  
  // Throws because StackOverflow snippets run as sandboxed
  sessionStorage.setItem(button.name, button.value); 
});
```

```html
<form action="/path/to/page-B" method=post>
  <button name="acces" value="choix 3">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And **page B** can get it from `sessionStorage` to select the corresponding option:

```js
const select = document.querySelector("select[data-original_id=liste]");

// Throws because StackOverflow snippets run as sandboxed
const optionValue = sessionStorage.getItem("acces"); // Use same name as button of page A!

if (optionValue !== null) {
  const option = select.querySelector(`option[value=${optionValue}]`);
  option.selected = true;
}
```

```html
<select data-original_id="liste">
  <option value="">liste</option>
  <option value="choix 1">je veux le 1</option>
  <option value="choix 2">je veux le 2</option>
  <option value="choix 3">je veux le 3</option>
</select>
```

## Query parameter

Data sent in a GET-request is part of the URL, as its [query string](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-query-string). So by using the method GET instead of POST, then:

- Page A can send the choice as a query parameter.
- Page B can retrieve the choice from its own URL; from the query string.
- Page B's URL with the query parameter *can be shared*; it will behave the same on the sharer's and sharee's browser, regardless of prior actions (e.g. submitting page A's form).

Simply change `method=post` in page A's form to `method=get`.

Then on page B, retrieve the choice from the current URL and select the corresponding option:

```js
const select = document.querySelector("select[data-original_id=liste]");

const optionValue = new URLSearchParams(location).get("acces"); // Use same name as button of page A!

if (optionValue !== null) {
  const option = select.querySelector(`option[value=${optionValue}]`);
  option.selected = true;
}
```

```html
<select data-original_id="liste">
  <option value="">liste</option>
  <option value="choix 1">je veux le 1</option>
  <option value="choix 2">je veux le 2</option>
  <option value="choix 3">je veux le 3</option>
</select>
```

Alternatively to selecting it in the front-end, you can [select the option on the back-end](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75648657/13561410) as well. Selecting on the back-end comes with the benefits of caching and JS-independence.

Comment: Hello, I tried the session storage code, but it doesn't work to me.

Comment: I tried Query parameter, and it's the same, not working to me, the list doesn't change at all.

Comment: @carosch You seem to have trouble with and questions regarding the provided answers. Perhaps you should update your question to reflect that, so that the community can improve their answers.

Comment: Make sure you spell acces the way it is spelled in the form field name